# Schema not generated by Widlfy

Tags: jpa, schema, wildfly

I have a project with entities. I want to generate database schema (at least in file) from entities tables. I am using Wildfly 30 and Java 21.0.1.

I made a persistence unit which is already detect and load by Wildfly.
However the create-drop scripts AND the schema are not generate.

Here is my persistence unit:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
             
    <persistence-unit name="MyPU">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        
        <!-- datasource -->
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/MariaDBDS</jta-data-source>

        
        <!-- activate 2nd level cache
         ENABLE_SELECTIVE: To cache only the entities annotated with @Cacheable or @Cacheable(true)
         -->
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        
        <properties> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
  
 
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" 
                      value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas" 
                         value="true"/>
                       
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" 
                      value="/home/lapin/database-scripts/create.sql"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" 
                      value="/home/lapin/database-scripts/drop.sql"/>
                     
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How can I automatically generate schema at webapp deployement ?
Thank you in advance

I am expecting database schema generate.

Thank you in advance